# Anythingslider + Fancybox duplicating images

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am in the process of rebuilding my website, using Anythingslider + Fancybox for my portfolio section but its currently duplicating same image twice. You can see what I mean here, scroll down to the folio section and click on the first image:

http://francisthedesigner.com/dev/

When I took it out of the Anythingslider the fancybox work as it should without duplicating image which confuses me, As you can tell I am no good at solving javascript issues but I am very keen to solve this issue.. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the HTML/JS code if it helps

```
<ul class="slider"> 
                <li> 
                    <a class="fancybox" rel="webfolio" href="images/folio/web_superjellyfish_b1.jpg">
                 <img src="images/folio/web_superjellyfish.jpg" alt="" />
                        </a>
                    <div class="caption-bottom"> 

                        <div>
                            <h3>Description</h3>
                            <p>An extract of my showreel about Go Up Communications’s works for fashion industry.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h3>Role</h3>
                            <p>Art Direction, Graphic Design, HTML5, CSS, Javascript, WP</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h3>Client</h3>
                            <p><a href="http://francisthedesigner.com/superjellyfish/&quot; target="_blank">Super Jellyfish</a></p>
                        </div>

                    </div> 
                    <span class="capLeft"></span>
                    <span class="capRight"></span>
                </li>
```

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
        prevEffect : 'true',
        nextEffect : 'true',

```
    closeBtn  : true,
    arrows    : true,
    nextClick : true,

    helpers: {
        title : {
            type : 'outside'
        },
        overlay : {
            speedIn : 500,
            opacity : 0.95
        },
        thumbs : {
                width: 75,
                height: 50
            },
        title : {
            type : 'inside'
        },
        //buttons   : {}
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="webfolio" href="images/folio/web_superjellyfish_b1.jpg" disabled="disabled" name="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; ">
    <img src="images/folio/web_superjellyfish.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

Seems that anythingslider is putting in extra images & they are being marked as `rel="webfolio"`, you need to stop anythingslider from doing this.

Comment: Hmm, do you have ay idea how to do that?

Comment: are you able to tell me how anythingslider is duplicating these <a> tags?

Comment: I have no idea why its doing so but I would have imagine the anything slider JS is messing with fancybox in someway for this to happen

Comment: Anyone else can shed a light on me?